# How to print reverse number pyramid like this one in c#?

Tags: c#, for-loop, nested-for-loop

i was trying to do thsi bellow pattern  but didn't understand it

```
1
3 2
6 5 4
10 9 8 7
```

this i what the basic increment number pattern i did

```
int counterNumPattern = 1;
      
        for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=i; j++)
            {
                Console.Write( counterNumPattern++);

               
                

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: Try to decide the first number for each line. You should be able to find some law in the sequence {1,3,6,10,...}. And Then, do decrement instead of increment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try to decide the first number for each line. You should be able to find some law in the sequence {1,3,6,10,...}. And Then, do decrement instead of increment.

I wrote as code:

```cs
const int NumberOfLines = 5;

//
int FirstNumberForLine = 0;
for( int i=1; i<=NumberOfLines; ++i )
{
    FirstNumberForLine += i;    //This is the law I found

    int Number = FirstNumberForLine;
    for( int j=1; j<=i; ++j )
    {
        Console.Write( Number-- );  //Decrement
        Console.Write( " " );   //Maybe need space
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```